# Edit HTML pages

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, html

I've got a little problem on CiviCrm. 
Do you know where can I find and edit the html file.

I know for the CSS but not for Html.

thank you for you help!

Ilena

Comment: Welcome Ilena!  There are some French speakers on this site, but far more English-speaking ones so you are more likely to get answers if you write in English.

Comment: Thanks for reposting your question in English. Would you be able to provide a bit more detail about which page you want to edit? Most pages are created from PHP templates so there isn't an HTML file to edit. Depending on what you want to change it may mean editing the PHP or writing some javascript to make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to edit the HTML.  Mostly that is not a good approach.  If you tell us more about what you want to achieve we can provide a different solution.

Comment: I need to change the H1 of the main page where there is the Home page.